# Sink configuration for Application Insights for Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

Where do I update the sink configuration for Azure Service Fabric
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/azure-diagnostics-configure-application-insights?

```
<SinksConfig>
    <Sink name="ApplicationInsights">
      <ApplicationInsights>{Insert InstrumentationKey}</ApplicationInsights>
      <Channels>
        <Channel logLevel="Error" name="MyTopDiagData"  />
        <Channel logLevel="Verbose" name="MyLogData"  />
      </Channels>
    </Sink>
</SinksConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

These settings is set as part of the cluster creation, when you setup a cluster from azure portal, you have to provide Application Insights Key as part of the setup and it will create for your.

If you used ARM templates, you have to configure it on wadCfg section of your template.

Please take a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-aggregation-wad) to know more

> Please take into account that these settings are targeted monitor and
>   log events from the cluster, if are planning to use these settings to
>   monitor you apps, I would recommend using EventFlow bundled in your
>   application. Because the cluster generally does not change as often as
>   your application does.

Comment: yes I have done the sink configuration which is in json format for arm template. What I am asking for the is the above setting which is in xml format

Comment: Sorry, was not clear in your question. 
If you pay attention to the schema, they both are the same, just the format is different, one is XML the other is JSON. The XML format is the way you see in the cluster manifest file and the JSON is the ARM template version, at the end, they will have the same results. If you already set on the ARM template, you don't have to worry about the manifest.